# jQuery function when clicked on button, then shows an animation and loads the new page

Tags: jquery, css, animation, href

I am working on my new portfolio website and I am trying to figure out how to do a simple animation when going to an another page, just so it seems a bit smoother.

I've made a `div` (`.pageOverlay`) on the page, with the `opacity: 0` property. When someone clicks on a button/link, I want it to fade in, and after it's completely faded in the new page loads.

The new page also starts with a black overlay that then fades out, so it looks like a smooth transition.​

.

.

**EDIT:**

This is the new code after some suggestions.
**jQuery** :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pageOverlay").css("opacity","0");
    $("a.newPage").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".pageOverlay").css("opacity","1");

        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        setTimeout(function() {window.location = href}, 2000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML** and **CSS** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/assets/css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/assets/vendor/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="pageOverlay"></div>
<a href="/portfolio" class="newPage">Test</a>
    
    div.pageOverlay {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        z-index: 999;
        background-color: #000000;
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        transition: .35s all ease-in-out;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
```

**Footer**

```
    <script src="/assets/vendor/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/initialize.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/default.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/pageload.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/vendor/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It still loads the new page immediately, but when i go back immediately after the new page is loaded in it goes to the new page again without me doing something.

I also found out than on my mobile device, the delay works! Only for some reason the overlay doesn't show up. On my laptop it is the other way around, the overlay shows up, but the delay does not work.

Comment: What is not working in your code? I think the problem is that the normal href url is executed immediately because you don't use `preventDefault()` on the event object.

Comment: @MarkBaijens it just immediately loads the new page. Where do i need to put the `preventDefault()` ?

Comment: I added an answer with the example code.

Comment: The new code seems to work just fine. Could it be that maybe the old code got cached? Try to open this new code in an Incognito tab.

Comment: @VladSolomon I've tried that, even on different devices but still the same!

Comment: @rutgervs This might be a longshot but can you show us your `<head>` from the `html` file?

Comment: @VladSolomon Added it

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the normal href url is executed immediately because you don't use preventDefault() on the event object. Try to add the `event` parameter to the event handler and add `event.preventDefault()` to the handler itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pageOverlay").css("opacity","0");
    $("a.newPage").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".pageOverlay").css("opacity","1");

        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        setTimeout(function() {window.location = href}, 1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
div.pageOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: .35s all ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pageOverlay"></div>
<a class="newPage" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">test</a>
```

Comment: One more thing that would be good is to give the `pageOverlay` the properties of `top: 0` and `left: 0` to make sure the overlay covers the whole page.

Comment: I did this exact code and it still goes to the page instantly. One thing that is weird, that if i go back to the page immediately after the new page is loaded, it goes to the new page again.

Comment: @VladSolomon The styling of the element is irrelevant to the OP problem or this answer. However your comment could be useful depending on the OP html structure. I'd suggest to post comments like this directly to the question instead to an answer.

Comment: @rutgervs can you update your answer with updated Javascript code and html so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @MarkBaijens i updated my answer with the new code!

Comment: @rutgervs I can not reproduce your issue with the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see no `script` tags in your `head` or `body`. That might be the problem.

**EDIT**

Fixed the problem. Just some missing classes and some redundant script tags.

Comment: I have them in my footer, i also posted it just now

Comment: When the page is loaded are there any errors in the debug console?

Comment: Can you add this line in your `head` and see if there are any changes?

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I added the line, but still no changes. I use jQuery more on my website so that works fine.

Comment: It's bets we start a chat room for now and return with a solution later.